# Restrict to maximum of one added message to the Azure Queue service using Shared Access Signatures

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

We have a requirement where we need to allow potentially many users to add one message to the Azure Queue Service. Using Shared Access Signatures we can allow users to add messages to the queue for a limited time. But is it also possible to restrict to a maximum of 1 message per SAS token we generate?
Or can a potentially malicious user insert an unlimited number of messages into the queue during the SAS token lifespan?

Answer (score 1):

> But is it also possible to restrict to a maximum of 1 message per SAS
>   token we generate?

Unfortunately not. The token is valid for the time period being issued, and the only limitation of messages sent is the Storage Queue limits.

> Or can a potentially malicious user insert an unlimited number of
>   messages into the queue during the SAS token lifespan?

Yes. This is a valid scenario.

As of today, if you want to have this granular control for a Queue (who sends what/when/how many), you have to gate the traffic yourself.

**UPDATE**

For Table it is different - you can restrict the SAS token to particular `PartitionKey` **and** particular `RowKey`, thus effectively making the SAS only capable of working with exactly one table row!

Check out the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn140255.aspx). There are parameters `spk` (start Part.Key), `srk` (Start RowKey), `epk` (End Part.Key), `erk` (End RowKey).

Using Table and Table SAS you can limit the data a single user can send! But the only way to limit the amount of data, or number of requests is by gating it yourself, or make the hard decision about the SAS lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I was afraid this was the case. So this kinda renders SAS useless for Queues in case you want to allow Apps or JS clients to Add messages to the Queue (or insert rows in the Azure Table Storage). I would assume it is not too hard to incorporate a param for maximum transactions per SAS token or something like that...